# asynchronous HTTP calls using EventMachine::Iterator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eventmachine

I am trying to make concurrent asynchronous HTTP calls using EventMachine::Iterator.  I see too many calls ended up in errcallback.  Is there any way to retry them?  I see all these have deferred_status failed.  How to avoid getting into that failed state.

```
urls = ["http://www.google.com"]*1000 #using this as an example
EventMachine.run do
  EM::Iterator.new(urls, 1000).map(proc { |url, iter|
    res = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(url).get
    sleep(0.100)
    res.callback {
      puts "#{res.req.uri} #{res.response_header.status}"
      response =(JSON.parse(res.response)['response']) if res.response_header.status == 200
      iter.return(response)
    }
    res.errback{
      puts "Err => #{res.req.uri} #{res.response_header.status}"
      iter.return(res.response_header.status)}
    }, proc { |responses|
    all = responses.flatten
    puts 'all done!'
    EM.stop
  })
end
```

Comment: Using `map` with a `proc` argument is odd. Why not `map do |...|`?

Comment: What exactly is the status code you are getting?

Comment: from documetation I found that errback only captures the requests with deferred_status failed.  So the HTTP response status is actually nil as the whole response object is nil.

Comment: @tadman because [EM::Iterator#map](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/d32fbaefa8bd954ae94918784e59cb033b2cdda0/lib/em/iterator.rb#L148) doesn't accept a block; it accepts two procs as arguments.